# How to send push notifications in swift 4 when something happens?

Tags: swift

I am creating an app in Swift 4 and I want it to send a push notification when the wind is above a specific value. I already have the app created and when you open the app you can see the current wind (scraped from a website).

Is it possible to send a message when my phone is turned off and the app isn't running? and how to do that?

Comment: You will need create a server that can create a push notification based your requirements.

Comment: Okay thanks, where can I find how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately that really comes down to preference on how to achieve that.  I prefer a python script that runs at a set time like every 15 min and checks if a condition is met and if it is it sends out the push notification.  You also need to have the paid developer account so that you can register your app for push notifications.

Comment: Ah okay, I program a lot with python but how to connect python with swift?

Comment: The python script will have to run on a sever or computer that is on 24/7 separate form the app.

Comment: @MwcsMac tnx, but isn't there another way? like WhatsApp notifications or is that something completely different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196153/discussion-between-mwcsmac-and-tijmen).

Comment: you can use firebase cloud messaging and use topic push notification. so when you implement the server code just need to sent the notification to the topic it will handle the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server to send push notifications when your phone is turned off.